# Is it possible to share Microsoft Store apps with Child accounts?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

I have bought a couple of apps in the Microsoft Store, that includes FS2020. I want my children to play as well. Do I need to buy them a separate copy or because they are added as Child in my account, only one purchase would suffice?

Thanks

Comment: Although there are many posts about how to do this (log in to your child's account, but use your account in the store, then install) I recently started getting a "no applicable app licenses found" on some of the installs. I could uninstall and re-install on all of the accounts, but only one would launch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can share application to your family. This link should help you. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps/sharing-apps-with-family-members-in-windows-10/afdde4f9-d58b-49a9-8b5d-1aad2599b987

Comment: Is this official? I recently started getting a "no applicable app licenses found" on accounts (kids in my family group) where I have a game installed using my store account. Re-installing the game doesn't help and only one of the accounts seems to work at any given time.